# Converting SAS SQL to Hive SQL

Tags: sql, sas, hiveql

I have to convert SAS SQL to hive sql Please help.
Below is the SAS code.

```
proc sql;
    create table master as
        select acct_nbr , clnt_nbr, card_typ from myquery.int_card
        order by 1,2 ;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table clnt_base as 
        select clnt_nbr ,
        (case when clnt_nbr in 
             (select clnt_nbr from master where crd_type in ('198',199')) then 1 else 0 end)
              as ultima 
         order by 1;
quit;
```

Please help!!

Comment: The second query is missing a `from` clause so it looks syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Code conversion is not on topic here; you can attempt to convert it and ask why things don't work (presenting your attempt), or you can ask how a particular thing works, but not just "here is my code, convert it" - that's something you should pay a consultant to do.  Please read the [faq] and the [help] for more information on how to write a good question.  Thanks!

Comment: These are pretty straightforward queries if you know either of the SQL languages. Which portion of the SAS code do you not understand?